# MySQL request - works very slow on db with 1000 records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have complex SQL request with a lot of joins (it's generated by PHP for table with different filters applied to show users data):

```
SELECT u.*,
       n.id AS network_id,
       n.name AS network_name,
       n.size AS network_size,
       count(distinct(un.userid)) AS network_elements_have,
       count(distinct(o.id)) AS total_orders,
       max(o.date) AS last_order_date,
       am.firstname AS am_firstname,
       am.surname AS am_surname,
       bdr.firstname AS bdr_firstname,
       bdr.surname AS bdr_surname,
       wc.status AS wc_status,
       wc.potential AS wc_potential,
       wc.calls AS wc_calls
FROM ei_users u
LEFT JOIN ei_orders o ON o.user_id=u.userid
LEFT JOIN ei_users am ON u.amid = am.userid
LEFT JOIN ei_users bdr ON u.bdrid = bdr.userid
LEFT JOIN ei_networks n ON u.network = n.id
LEFT JOIN ei_users un ON n.id=un.network
AND un.archive != '1'
LEFT JOIN ei_calls wc ON wc.userid = u.userid
AND wc.type = 'welcome'
WHERE u.archive != '1'
GROUP BY u.userid
HAVING last_order_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY
ORDER BY u.userid DESC,
         o.date DESC
```

When I run this request on a MySQL table (ei_users) with 1755 users and 75000 orders (ei_orders table) it's works very slow (10+ minutes or so). All id's and used in request fields have index'es added in all tables.

Question:

1. How to make this work faster? (we use shared Siteground hosting, but maybe we can enable some database caching or some other modules or you have ideas how to optimize some part of request here)
2. What requests parts in this SQL code are MOST time consuming? (as I see main problem here is dates intervals). How we can run this request (for ex. in PHPMyAdmin or via PHP) in some kind of debug mode so we can see what parts of request how much time consume?

*Maybe someone can provide fixed version of my EXAMPLE query provided here, so I can understand better what is wrong here?*

EXPLAIN query:
[image: sql explain]

Comment: The query is malformed. On one side you have a `LEFT JOIN ei_orders o ON ...` but you also have `HAVING last_order_date < ...` that defeats the LEFT JOIN. Which one is it?

Comment: ... likewise for wc and un

Comment: Why it defeats it? Request works correctly and show correct result.

Comment: The query is also malformed since many columns are not aggregated in the query and they are not in the `GROUP BY` clause either. This tool you are using seems to be low quality.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query. Incidentally, if you execute EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query] followed by SHOW WARNINGS;, you might be able to see the point The Impaler was making more clearly

Comment: Actually, as The Impaler has mentioned, if this query returns the 'desired' result at all, it's only by sheer luck. Far better to start over. Accordingly, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @The Impaler What others columns needs to be added to GROUP BY? And why, if at the end I need only data for every user (so only users id's grouped here). What do you mean by "Not aggregated"?

Comment: @Strawberry I understand about MCRE but I'm not sure how to provide it. This request use 5 tables, some of them have around 50 columns with different data, and this request is not generated by me - it's generated by PHP MySQL framework that create this request automatically based of some code added (I just specify what data I need, what tables to join, etc). I does not specify exactly all request, it's parts order, etc - most of all generated by framework.

Comment: And since request itself based on 50+ possible filters combinations (2000+ lines of PHP code) it can be totally different. I am not sure how to provide SQL tables example here :) This example will have text amount like a book.

Comment: Maybe someone can provide fixed version of my EXAMPLE query provided here, so I can understand better what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't know exactly what filters you have in mind, but I would try to make the query as modular and compartmentalised as possible. For example instead of joining all tables directly to users and then `GROUP BY` you could `GROUP BY` in subqueries. Ex: `SELECT ... FROM user u LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user_id, count(...), ... FROM orders GROUP BY user_id) AS o ON u.userid = o.user_id`

Comment: We can see from the above that only 15 or so columns are relevant to this problem. Everyone else manages this, so I can't think why your problem would be an exception.

Comment: @Pepper as I see I can't make requests like this using framework ( https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class ) . It only be possible with SQL RAW queries, but I need to avoid this.

Comment: I see :s In that case, assuming someone finds a way to improve your query, will you be able to use said improvement? Either way, as mentioned in earlier comments, you should definitely add the result of `EXPLAIN [your query]` to your question, it can only help people understand what your database is doing behind the scenes

Comment: @Pepper - added EXPLAIN image to post. As I understand PHPMyAdmin limit query to 25 rows (for paginated results) by default and does not actually get all data.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding index on repeatedly used columns. That would speed up the select query.

Comment: Indexes already added to all this columns. Yes it's speed up's query but not enough.

Comment: try removing where condition and add that to first join statement  "LEFT JOIN ei_orders o ON o.user_id=u.userid and u.archive != '1' "